# Will NextCursorMark be valid when documents gets reindexed in Apache Solr?

Tags: solr, solrj

When there is a change in core and the document gets reindexed will the nextCursorMark that i already got will be valid or not. If not how to handle such cases?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the cursorMark will still be valid. A cursorMark is completely stateless, meaning that any changes to the index won't make it invalid.

It will not include documents inserted before the mark in the index either (which would make the same document be displayed twice - in the last position on the previous page and the first on the new page).

Think of the cursorMark as an identifier saying "we've moved so far into the result set that any documents any document that sort in front of this key has already been shown".